# What list(operation) would be the swap type in SmartPY?

Tags: smartpy

Trying to create a type to represent the swap type here: https://github.com/madfish-solutions/quipuswap-core-v2/blob/master/contracts/partial/dex_core/dex_core_types.ligo#LL121-L121C5

Any idea what that list(operation) would be in SmartPY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SmartPy we manage operation for you so most of the time you don't need to manipulate the type TOperation.
`TOperation` refers to the operation (transfer, create_contract, etc.) returned by a lambda, an entrypoint, etc.
For example: `sp.TLambda(sp.TUnit, sp.TNat, with_operation=True)` is kinda a syntaxic sugar for something like `sp.TLambda(sp.TUnit, sp.TPair(sp.TNat, sp.TList(sp.TOperation)))`. SmartPy unpairs the lambda's result and call `sp.add_operations(...)` for you with the list of returned operations.

SmartPy offers equivalent for everything that generates operation so you can manage them by yourself. For example `sp.transfer_operation` is the equivalent of `sp.transfer` where the resulting operation is returned instead of being automatically added to the list of operations managed by SmartPy and returned by the entrypoint.

**Question and answer from Smartpy Telegram.**